# Parse registerSubclass() error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Only one of my PFSubclasses is giving me the following error:

```
'The class AppName.Offer must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse.'
```

Even though I am indeed calling registerSubclass() on that class in the AppDelegate. Any ideas as to why it thinks the class still isn't registered (causing the crash)?

Code from the PFSubclass:

```
class Offer: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

  class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Offer"
  }
```

Code from the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions():

```
    Offer.registerSubclass()
    Parse.setApplicationId(kStagingAppID, clientKey: kStagingClientKey)
```

Comment: The dot notation on the class name is strange.  Are you sure the class isn't named just `Offer`?

Comment: @danh Yes, the class is named "Offer". But in the error message it does say AppName.Offer for some reason.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: @danh Updated the question with more of my code

Comment: Hmm.  The way i do it in Obj-C is (a) often don't do it, because I've found numerous liabilities to this approach vs. "wrapping" a PFObject in my local model class, but more to your question (b) have the class register itself by overriding `+load` and from there calling `self.registerSubclass()`.  Another thing to try (random stab) is to swap the order of setApplicationId and registerSubclass.

Comment: @danh Oddly enough, the error was only happening when I was instantiating these Offer objects vs just declaring them as an empty variable. I will provide code in an answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have avoided the crash by changing the way I was declaring members of this class in my ViewController.

Instead of:

```
var offer = Offer()
```

I have to do:

```
var offer: Offer!
```

Hope this helps someone.